# Magento - Determine if coupon code applied on cart page is for 'FREE SHIPPING'

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

Does any one know how to determine that the coupon code applied on shopping cart page is for Free Shipping through code?

I have a Shopping Cart rule created for FREE SHIPPING which works fine. But if a customer hasn't yet chosen his shipping delivery options then its confusing for them coz the coupon code does nothing for them atleast on the cart page.

They see FREE SHIPPING option on the checkout/onepage.

Hence I would need this information so that I can display the customer a valid message that the 'Coupon is applied and FREE SHIPPING option would be available to them in the next stage of Checkout'

Any ideas which file to look for and what piece of code can help me determine that my coupon code in question is for FREE SHIPPING ?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look in `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` and than the method `public function processFreeShipping(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)`. That's where the free shipping is calculated.

You can modify/extend this to save something in session and use that to detect on frontend when the cart has free shipping or not.

Comment: Oh Okk... I can have a look at it and see if I find anything useful. If yes I'l post in here for others to have a look too. Thanks.

Comment: That file does get affected and using that function I want to display an additional line just after Subtotal. How do i do that? any ideas?

Comment: Bit late, but for the record... You can find a good guide to adding total lines here: http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-development-add-total-row-checkout/